durability: command not found Error in Jenkins Pipeline
I have a jenkinsfile in which a stage block is giving me durability error in which the console output shows a temp script on a temporary path. I have searched for this issue and could see various answers but it is still not resolving my error. Below is my block of code that is giving me error :


stages {
        stage('Run Install script') {
            steps {
                 sh '''#!/bin/bash -e
                    cd /sapcomm/zip/dxc-eshops/installer
                    bash install.sh -r cx -A initAdminPassword=nimda
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                 sh '''#!/bin/bash -e
                    cd /sapcomm/zip/dxc-eshops/hybris/bin/platform
                    . ./setantenv.sh
                    ant clean all
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Ant Initialize') {
            steps {
                 sh '''#!/bin/bash -e
                    cd /sapcomm/zip/dxc-eshops/hybris/bin/platform
                    ant initialize
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Run Server') {
            steps {
                 sh '''#!/bin/bash -e
                    cd /sapcomm/zip/dxc-eshops/hybris/bin/platform
                   bash hybrisserver.sh
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}

and the error is below:
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Ant Initialize)
[Pipeline] sh
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/dxceshop@tmp/durable-3524078f/script.sh.copy: line 3: durability: command not found

I have checked various articles on google and on jenkins website. one of the article mentions that it is  bug :
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69122

Is this specific to AWS in any way?

pipeline is hosted on ECS instance

Your log and the script do not match. The error message clearly says that line 3 of your shell script starts with a word durability and it's not a known command in bash.

Apologies. I don't understand your reply.
However, the script (script.sh) is a runtime script which i have not set up. It is automatically shows in log when pipeline is failing. On further checking, i have seen few articles where it is being mentioned that this is a jenkins error and occurs when pipeline script is too complex or big.

Below is my block of code if there is more surrounding this block, please share it if possible. I also think that there is some context missing from the question.

I have updated the whole block of code for different stages in jenkinsfile. Also, can you share what more context are you expecting? I will try to explain in detail then
